# Creating VBA Chart using Array

Tags: vba, excel

I am trying to create a excel chart using vb6. Instead of feeding a excel range im trying to feed an array. And im getting an error.
This is the code that im working on

```
Private Sub CreateChart(Optional ByVal ChartTitle As String _
                , Optional ByVal xAxis As Excel.Range _
                , Optional ByVal yAxis As Excel.Range _
                , Optional ByVal ColumnName As String _
                , Optional ByVal LegendPosition As XlLegendPosition = xlLegendPositionRight _
                , Optional ByVal rowIndex As Long = 2 _
                , Optional ByRef ChartType As String = xlLineMarkers _
                , Optional ByVal PlotAreaColorIndex As Long = 2 _
                , Optional ByVal isSetLegend As Boolean = False _
                , Optional ByVal isSetLegendStyle As Boolean = False _
                , Optional ByVal LegendStyleValue As Long = 1)

Const constChartLeft = 64
Const constChartHeight = 300
Const constChartWidth = 700

Dim xlChart As Excel.ChartObject
Dim seriesCount As Long
Dim ColorIndex As Long

Dim j As Long


With mWorksheet
    .Rows(rowIndex).RowHeight = constChartHeight

    Set xlChart = .ChartObjects.Add(.Rows(rowIndex).Left, .Rows(2).Top, constChartWidth, constChartHeight)
End With

With xlChart.chart
    .ChartType = ChartType
    .SetSourceData Source:=marrayPOClient, PlotBy:=marrayPOSKU
    .SeriesCollection(1).XValues = marrayPOClient
    .HasTitle = True

    .Legend.Position = LegendPosition
    .Legend.Font.Size = 7.3
    .Legend.Font.Bold = True
    .Legend.Border.LineStyle = xlNone

    .ChartTitle.Characters.Text = ChartTitle
    .ChartTitle.Font.Bold = True

    .Axes(xlValue).TickLabels.Font.Size = 8 ' yAxis Labels
    .Axes(xlCategory).TickLabels.Font.Size = 8 ' xAxis Labels

    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = PlotAreaColorIndex
    .PlotArea.Interior.ColorIndex = 15
    .PlotArea.Interior.PatternColorIndex = 1
    .PlotArea.Interior.Pattern = xlSolid
End With
End Sub
```

Is it possible to use array for chart. If possible what are my mistakes.

Comment: *And im getting an error* - it would be useful to tell us exactly what error you're getting.

Comment: @Mat'sMug it says "Object Required"

Comment: Good, that's a start... does a line of code or specific function call get highlighted?

Comment: @Mat'sMug the error occured in this line of code
    `.SetSourceData Source:=marrayPOClient, PlotBy:=marrayPOSKU`

Comment: Just be aware that if you use an array there are limits as to how much data it can contain, because you are constrained by the maximum length of the series formula.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

As Mat's Mug says, `SetSourceData` requires a `Range`, but you can achieve the result using another method

Replace

```
.SetSourceData Source:=marrayPOClient, PlotBy:=marrayPOSKU
```

with

```
.SeriesCollection.NewSeries
.SeriesCollection(1).Values = marrayPOClient
```

This will create a new series without a source, then assign the array as the series values

Comment: I realize this is a hella old question. When I use this method, my second and third values get to the graph but all plot 0. In the select data window the values are correct, but the plotted points are 0. First series works great.

Answer (score 0):

[Chart.SetSourceData](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/office/ff841196.aspx) requires a `Range` object for its `Source` parameter, and an `XlRowCol` enum value for its `PlotBy` parameter.

I'm **assuming** both `marrayPOClient` and `marrayPOSKU` are *arrays* as their names imply (you haven't shown where they're declared and how they're assigned, so we can't know their type or value), but you need to supply a `Range` for the first parameter and, optionally, either `xlColumns` or `xlRows` for the second parameter.

Comment: that's what I thought too. Is there any other way to do it? I tried using `chart.values` but still failed. The error says "Invalid Parameter"